# How to fetch nested data in react

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

Question regarding fetching nested data in react.

APIs

1. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
2. [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/$%7BpostId%7D/comments)

Able to fetch list of posts. now want to fetch list of comments from when click on post

here is code so far

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Post from "./Post";

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const loadposts = async() => {
    const resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1");
    const data = await resp.json();
    setPosts(data);
  }
  loadposts();
}, []);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => 
      (
        <div>
          <li key={post.id}>
            <Post 
            userId={post.id}
            title={post.title} 
            body={post.body} 
            />
          </li>
      </div>
      ))
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}

export default App;

function Post({title, body, postId}) {
  
  return (
      <div>
          <h5>{postId}</h5>
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p>{body}</p>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Post
```

appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: So you've the API endpoint for fetching comments by post id and a child `Post` component and `postId` prop. Have you tried making the request to the endpoint with the specific data? When do you want, or need, to fetch the comments for each post?

Comment: @Drew Reese .. Thanks for getting back.  I did add request to fetch comments with given {post id} when click on post title but it did not return anything

Comment: SHow us what you tried. There isn't any onClick code shown here

Comment: What and where are you clicking *something*?

Comment: @DrewReese I  would like to display selected post fetch data from comments when I  click on post. I added handleclick  on title function in case   currentpostId === post.id. but it did not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the "/posts" endpoint returns posts by users, so the query "/posts?userId=1" will return all the posts by user id `1`. You mistakenly passed a `userId` prop to the `Post` component instead of the specific post's `id`, i.e.

```
<Post userId={post.id} title={post.title}  body={post.body} />
```

The React key should also be placed on the outer-most element being mapped, the `div` in your case, but since `li` is already a block level element the `div` is basically extraneous.

```
<ul>
  {posts.map((post) => (
    <li key={post.id}> // <-- remove div and place React key on li
      <Post
        postId={post.id} // <-- pass the post's id
        title={post.title}
        body={post.body}
      />
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

In `Post` component create a fetch comments utility and click handler, and attach the click handler to the title header. Conditionally render the comments. If it wasn't already clear, you'll move the `comments` state into `Posts` so each post component maintains its own copy. The following is an example for rendering out the comments once fetched, you can use whatever conditional rendering and field subset of your choosing.

```
const fetchComments = async (postId) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}/comments`
  );
  return response.json();
};

function Post({ title, body, postId }) {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    fetchComments(postId).then(setComments);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>{postId}</h5>
      <h1 onClick={clickHandler}>{title}</h1>
      <p>{body}</p>
      {comments.length && (
        <>
          Comments:
          <ul>
            {comments.map(({ id, email, name, body }) => (
              <li key={id}>
                <dl>
                  <dt>{email} - {name}</dt>
                  <dd>{body}</dd>
                </dl>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-fetch-nested-data-in-react]

Answer (score 0):

Working solution if anyone looking for

```
function Post() {
const {id} = useParams();
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}/comments`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(setComments)
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    console.log("setComments: ", setComments)
}, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {comments && comments.map((comment) => (
                <div key={comment.id}>
                    <p>{comment.body}</p>
                </div>

            ))}

        </div>
    )
}
export default Post

then update rendering 

    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/'>
        {posts.map((post) => (
         <article key={post.id}> 
          <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <Link to ={`/${post.id}`}>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
            </Link>
       </article>
      ))}
   </Route>

     <Route path ='/:id'>
        <Post/>
     </Route>
   </Switch>

  </div>
```